# Set the value of TextBox inside HyperlinkButton.Content in .cs

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Currently I have a HyperlinkButton:

```
<HyperlinkButton 
   Name="HyperLinkNav" 
   FontSize="24"
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Foreground="White">
       <HyperlinkButton.Content>test</HyperlinkButton.Content>
 </HyperlinkButton>
```

And In my code behind i've got:

```
HyperLinkNav.Content = "Please select a link";
```

Which sets the `<HyperlinkButton>` content to 'Please select a link'.

What I would like to do is alter the template for the `<HyperlinkButton>` to contain a `TextBox`, something like this:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">  
                        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>--> 
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="TextElement" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>  
                    </Border>
```

This will then allow me to add a TextBox to the HyperlinkButton:

```
 <HyperlinkButton.Content> 
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
            <TextBlock Text="Next Page"/>  
            <Image Source="SampleImageResource.jpg" Width="50" Height="50"/>  
        </StackPanel> 
 </HyperlinkButton.Content>
```

However I need to update the code behind so that instead of updating the `<HyperlinkButton>.Content` it updates the `TextBlock`.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<HyperlinkButton.Content> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB" Text="Next Page"/>  
        <Image Source="SampleImageResource.jpg" Width="50" Height="50"/>  
    </StackPanel> 
</HyperlinkButton.Content>
```

and in the code-behind:

```
TB.Text = "Please select a link";
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want. I've tried to answer what I understood from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *should* work for you:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TB" Text="{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type HyperlinkButton}}, Path=TargetName} ... />
```

In practice, you bind its `Text` to first occured ancestor of type `HyperlinkButton`'s `TargetName`. In this way, you *should* be able to continue to code like  so

```
HyperLinkNav.TargetName= "Please select a link";
```